# Error in AutoLaunch flow: xxx (Action) - The process type 'Autolaunched Flow' only supports 'CurrentTransaction' in 'FlowTransactionModel'

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, apexactionfunction

I have a screen flow in Salesforce. I saved this flow as a New Flow and changed the type to "Autolaunched Flow (No Trigger)". But this flow has many Apex Actions and for every Apex Action, I have the following error:

> my_apex_action (Action) - The process type 'Autolaunched Flow' only
> supports 'CurrentTransaction' in 'FlowTransactionModel'

It won't let me save this flow with this error. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please edit your question and add a screenshot of your flow. When you have a chance, read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour).

Comment: check the flow's version

Comment: @identigral my question doesn't need a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I went down this rabbit hole too. Found that the FlowTransactionModel is part of how the Flow is structured:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm
Two ways to get at this. I first went about retrieving the flow via VS Code and saw I could edit the transaction model through the .flow-meta.xml file.
[image]

Following that I got around to poking in the Advanced controls of the individual actions. Found it! Looks like option 1 is Automatic, option 2 is NewTransaction, and option 3 (our desired here) is CurrentTransaction. Oddly, it took around 10 seconds on my end for this portion of Advanced to load. But it's there!
[image]